# Declare, then define a class method - Why an error?

Tags: c++

Why doesn't this compile?

```
class Test
{
    void foo();
    void foo()
    { }
};
```

But these will compile:

```
void bar();
void bar()
{ }

// In same header/file
class Test
{
    void foo();   
};
void Test::foo()
{ }
```

The compiler would say that given method [cannot be overloaded](http://ideone.com/d0CKiZ). The method `Test::foo` is not being overloaded - it is the same function with exact same signature.

Comment: @StoryTeller ^ that should be an answer :)

Comment: Each member must be declared inside a class exactly once. Each definition is also a declaration.

Comment: @StoryTeller good answers do not require a standard quote! especially for something like this.  Answers with standard quotes are if correct good answers though

Comment: @Curious - I have a very strong opinion about answers I give or vote on. But NVM, it's actually one small quote :)

Comment: @StoryTeller what do you mean?  I don't think I follow...

Comment: @Curious - I mean I have a very restricting view in my mind of what is a good answer. And I don't feel my comment was that. But it's all moot, since I posted an actual answer.

Comment: @StoryTeller I will try and employ the same logic to my answers in the future!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's explicitly prohibited by the C++ standard. Right there at [[class.mfct/1]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class#mfct-1)

> A member function may be defined in its class definition, in which
>   case it is an inline member function, or it may be defined outside of
>   its class definition if it has already been declared but not defined
>   in its class definition. A member function definition that appears
>   outside of the class definition shall appear in a namespace scope
>   enclosing the class definition. **Except for member function definitions
>   that appear outside of a class definition**, and except for explicit
>   specializations of member functions of class templates and member
>   function templates ([temp.spec]) appearing outside of the class
>   definition, **a member function shall not be redeclared.**

Comment: Doesn't state why global function declaration/definition is allowed the exact same way, but not while inside a class.

Comment: @Ajay - Of course it's stated as allowed, in another section about **free function** declarations. This is about **members**, and is explicit in the quote.

Answer (score 1):

It is just the way it is in C++. Redeclaring a class member is not allowed (unless you consider an out-of-class *definition* as another *declaration*). Redeclaring a namespace member is OK as long as you obey ODR.

Comment: There has to be a valid reason. `T x()` doesn't call a constructor, but a function declaration, since C++ compiler must first consider C language rules. Similarly, ODR rule cannot be different for free vs. class level functions.

Answer (score 1):

> Why doesn't this compile?

```
class Test {
  void foo();
  void foo() { }; // wrong
};
```

Because, as [StoryTeller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44693145/841108) and others answered, you are declaring and defining the *same* member function `void Test::foo(void)` twice (and the inside-class definition of `foo` is implicitly `inline`).

If you want to define a member function in your header file *after* the class, you'll better declare it explicitly as `inline` like this:

```
class Test {
   inline void foo();
};
```

and *later* define that member function (e.g. below in the same header file):

```
void Test::foo() {
  // body of Test::foo
}
```

BTW, if you declare a member function with outside definition like above, and that member function is not `inline` but is *defined* in some header file which is included in several translation units, that function would be multiply defined and the linker would complain.

Comment: It's easy to forget how important the inline specifier is for proper linkage in cases like this. +1

Comment: What inline has to do with declaration/definition? We can do the same with global functions, but not with class methods. Why? Also, even if 'inline' attribute is applied to a free function, it still compiles.

Comment: You could have issues at link time.

Answer (score 0):

```
void foo();
```

and

```
void foo() {}
```

are two ways of declaring functions in a class definition. The first only declares the function and the second declares the function and also  implements it. Therefore the compiler assumes that you are going to re-declare the same function and is not a correct overload as the function signature is the same in both.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.